Incorrect code coverage on every run using Gcovr
We are observing incorrect code coverage of C++ project on every run (Linux, Gcovr). Please find below our observations:

All the object files, gcno, gcda, libraries are being generating.
All the 147 test cases are getting passed successfully.
There are 600+ files for which coverage is shown but for few files (0-15 files) only code coverage is always incorrect and for rest of the files coverage is always constant. For example: In one run code coverage is incorrect for 10 files in next run coverage is incorrect for 14 files.
For one file we have observed 0% code coverage but we found that the functions of that files are getting successfully called.

Also, there is a difference in the number of lines and branches in the total count highlighted in the attached pictures.


As per our understanding the total number of lines and branches should be constant because they are calculated at the compilation time (flag used -fPIC -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage) and should be in gcno files. Please correct, if our understanding is wrong.
Why there is a difference in the total number of lines and branches count?
If all the binaries are getting generated and all the testcases are successfully executed. What could be cause of incorrect code coverage of few files only every time?
How we can correct our code coverage?
Note: Its a C++ client project. We checked the behavior with other projects also but out of 6 projects, 4 projects are working fine with no code coverage issues.

Do you use optimization? some line/branch might no longer exist with some optimization

That's not code coverage.  That's code coverage summaries, which are not of much interest. And never should be shared with management, because they will use them as a metric, and hence misapply them.

@Jarod42: Yes -O2 is used.

You might want to ask your question on gcovr issues.  Could be a gcov issue.  Could be a gcc issue.  Can you make a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?

@Eljay: Thanks, Yes this is the code coverage summary and it is not constant on every run. What could be the possible reason?

What could be the possible reason?  I think there is a bug.  But is the bug in gcc, or in gcov, or in gcovr?

Before looking for bugs in 3rd parties, ask yourself if your tests are really reproductible.
If they depend on timings/random/network, it is likely that they don't execute the same way on each run, so you have different coverage results.

As an aside, in  a previous, somewhat related post, you state that you're using "gcov (GCC) 4.8.5" which is almost a decade old: is that still the case?  If so, it might be worth testing your code against a more recent tool chain to see if these apparent anomalies are still present.

@Eljay, Thanks, I have also asked on on gcovr issues. I tried with some opensource builds.

@Steve, Thanks, I will check.

@G.M. Yes, when we were on RHEL7 but now we have migrated to RHEL8 and now the gcov (GCC) version is 8.5.0. But still we are getting the same behavior.
